# Controlling layout of multiple histograms

Tags: stata

I have used the `by` option of the `histogram` command to group my two categorical variables:

```
sysuse auto, clear
hist price, percent by(foreign rep78)
```

[image]

I would like to graph `8` histograms together on the same plot, with the following layout:

```
XXXX  
XXXX
```

However, as the above graph shows Stata places the histograms by default as follows:

```
XXX  
XXX  
XX
```

How can I achieve a `2x4` orientation of histograms?

I have played around with the `aspectratio()` option, but this changes the aspect ratio of the individual graphs, not of the whole plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `cols()` sub-option in `by()`:

```
sysuse auto, clear
histogram price, percent by(foreign rep78, cols(4))
```

[image]